# Wrong use of function

Tags: c, function

I am trying to obtain the same result by performing a test directly in the program (test 1) and through calling a function that does the same thing (test 2).

The test is supposed to test if there are 2 identical numbers on a line or a column of a sudoku grid.

Test 1 executes in the program and works as expected.

For test 2 I want to call a function instead. The program runs but a wrong grid remains undetected.

A valid grid is rightly considered valid and printed.

Am I using the function wrong?

```
int check(char s[10][10]);

main()

{  
  char s[10][10]; /*solution for current tile*/  
  int rw; /*number deciding if solution check is right or wrong*/  
  int i, j, k, l;


  /*proper grid building*/  
  printf("Enter a proper 4x4 sudoku grid.\nType . for empty square.\nType return for new line.\n");
  
  for(i=1; i<=4; ++i)  
    for(j=1; j<=5; ++j)  
      {  
    scanf("%c", &s[i][j]);  
    if(s[i][j] == '.' || j == 5 && s[i][j] == '\n' || j < 5 && s[i][j] != '\n' && s[i][j] >= 49 && s[i][j] <= 52)  
      ;  
    else
      {  
        printf("Instructions not followed.\n");  
        exit(0);  
      }  
      }

                 
  /*Test 1*/    
  for(i=1; i<=4; ++i)  
    for(j=1; j<=4; ++j)  
      for(k=1; k<=4; ++k)  
    {  
      if(k != j && s[i][k] == s[i][j] && s[i][k] != '.' || k != i && s[k][j] == s[i][j] && s[k][j] != '.')  
        {  
          printf("Improper grid.\n");  
          exit(0);  
        }  
        }  

  /*Test 2*/  
   if((rw = check (s)) < 1)  
    {  
      printf("Improper grid.\n");  
      exit(0);  
    }  

  printf("\n");
  for(i=1; i<=4; ++i)
    for(j=1; j<=5; ++j)
      printf("%c", s[i][j]);

}  



int check(char a[10][10])  

{  
  int i, j, k, l;  
  int r; /*checks result/*  

    /*check doubles on lines and columns*/  
  for(i=1; i<=4; ++i)  
    for(j=1; j<=4; ++j)  
      for(k=1; k<=4; ++k)  
    {  
      if(k != j && a[i][k] == a[i][j] && a[i][k] != '.' || k != i && a[k][j] == a[i][j] && a[k][j] != '.')  
        r = 0;  
      else  
        r = 1;  
        }  
  return r;  

}
```

Comment: Please indent correctly your code

Comment: I did my best. Very first program, sorry. Will do better next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first code prints error immediately when it finds a problem. Your function continues and sets `r` to zero or one going through the whole thing and only the last value is returned.

If you want identical functionality then replace `r = 0;` with `return 0;` and the `return r;` with `return 1;` and it will be equivalent.